# How to Changing button on click color to none and shrink it

Tags: wpf, silverlight, button, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Below is my windows 8 html 5 app code

```
<Button Click="Button_Click_2" Content="" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="9,22,9,23">
   <Button.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Image/Resized-CQ18G.png"/>
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

I want the button to shrink instead of displaying the accent color brush. I searched but i couldnt find any working examples.

Comment: sorry about that the code was not posted properly

Comment: Do you want the button to be smaller only for as long as it is pressed or do you want it to stay smaller even after the user released the mousebutton again?

Comment: As long as the user pressed it.

Comment: sorry I thought you're using Desktop XAML. For HTML XAML (used in Windows Phone), you should search more about its `Style`. Looks like that `Style` is totally different from the `Style` in Desktop XAML, which does not support `Triggers`. I deleted my answer, Windows Phone is not my field. You should try asking this question again and remember to include tag such as `windows-phone-8`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit the button template to change its pressed behaviour. It's not clear what type of app you mean by "Windows 8 html 5 app" (likely a Windows Store app, but your snippet is Xaml not Html), but the basic concept is the same for all Xaml targets.

The easiest way to do this is in Blend.

Right click on your button and select Edit Template.Edit a Copy... to create a copy of the Button Template and go into the Template editor. This will let you edit the look and feel of the Button.

[image: Edit Template menu item]

To clear out the old behaviour go to source view, find the Pressed VisualState, and delete its Storyboard, then go back to the design pane. Leave the state itself:

To change the pressed behaviour to what you want go back to the design pane, select the States tab, and choose the "Pressed" state. You should see a notification "Pressed state recording is on".

[image: Blend's States pane]

Change the bits of the button template you want to change and set the properties to what you want in the Pressed state. To make it smaller, set RenderTransform to scale:

[image: Blend's RenderTransform property pane]

You can also set transition times in the States pane to make the change smoother.

Your final state will be something like:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

And you'll want to do something similar for the PointerOver state. I had the border turn a custom accent colour:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MyCustomAccentBrush}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks a million Rob. It really worked. After spending long hours searching here and there I never ever dreamt it will be this Eassssyyy!! Thanks again Rob